# WordPress, custom single page content

Tags: wordpress, templates, post, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to get a custom single page to spit out the title and content of the post, the title works fine, the content of the post doesn't seem to want to come through. I don't work much in wordpress so I am in the dark here, can someone tell me how to fix this? Here is my single-news.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="decade1">
<?php

echo get_the_title().'<br/>'; //Output titles of queried posts
echo get_the_content().'<br/>';

?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You need the WordPress Loop for those functions to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [WordPress Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) before using tags like `get_the_title()`.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="decade1">
  <?php
  if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
      echo get_the_title() . '<br/>'; 
      echo get_the_content() . '<br/>';
    } // end while
  } // end if
  ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_content()` must be use in loop.

syntax:

```
get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser )
```

where `$more_link_text` and `$stripteaser` are optional.
[read about it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)

and `get_the_title()` will output title only when it is in loop, otherwise you have to provide post id to display title.

```
get_the_title($post_id)
```