# Not selector: how to exclude single pages form CSS customization in WordPress with :not()?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am a CSS noob and completely PHP ignorant. I am trying to remove the header image from all pages except the homepage in WordPress.

I found [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005313/wordpress-custom-single-page-content), but it is beyond my understanding, since I don't know any PHP. Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr#9110350) and to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr), in the *css customizer* I tried to add:

```
:not(.home) header-image {display: none;}
```

**However, it does not work.**

Note that this can be applied to any single page, not only the homepage. For instance with `.page-id-123` instead of `.home` –– this also works, of course, if `.page-id-123` is the homepage, whereas `123` is just a random page id here.

### Question:

How to use the not selector `:not()` to exclude all pages except one from CSS customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `:not` selector like this to hide an element on all pages except homepage:

```
body:not(.home) .header-image {
display: none;
}
```